# Why can I not define two pointers at once?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've got some code that did not work, where the solution was very simple: simply writing it all in a longer way. Namely, the following:

I know that the following is correct code:

```
int main() {
    int a = 1,
        b = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

But I was surprised to see that the following gives an error:

```
struct Foo {
    int a = 0;
};


int main() {
    Foo* f = new Foo;
    Foo* x = f,
         y = f;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
error: conversion from ‘Foo*’ to non-scalar type ‘Foo’ requested
          y = f;
              ^
```

Even though it would work if you'd replace the definition of `x` and `y` with:

```
Foo* x = f;
Foo* y = f;
```

So could someone explain why this is not allowed (or redirect me to the inevitable other SO question that explains this, which I could not find by this error)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why the common C++ style of writing `Foo* x`, instead of `Foo *x` as is preferred style in C, is wrong wrong wrong.

Unary `*` acts on the thing to its *right*, not on the thing to its left.  Your

```
Foo* x = f,
     y = f;
```

means the same as

```
Foo *x = f;
Foo y = f;
```

If you want to stick to the shorthand, you have to write an asterisk for each variable you're declaring:

```
Foo *x = f,
    *y = f;
```

Modifiers like `const` are the opposite; they modify the thing to their left.

```
Foo const x, y;
```

is the same as

```
Foo const x;
Foo const y;
```

But watch out for

```
Foo *const x,
    *y;
```

where `x` is a *const pointer* to *non-const Foo* and `y` is a *non-const pointer* again to non-const Foo.

(Nowadays in both C and C++, the preferred style is to write only one variable declaration per semicolon, and that really is a lot less confusing.  I will occasionally still write `int i, j, k;` but only when it's that simple.)

Answer (score 4):

```
Foo* x = f,
y = f;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Foo* x = f;
Foo y = f;
```

You need to add another `*`:

```
Foo* x = f,
*y = f;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Foo* x = f,
       y = f;
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
  Foo* x = f,
  Foo  y = f;
```

As you can see, the `x` and `y` are not of the same type. Hence, the error.

This is one of the "features" of C and C++. Personally I always attach the `*` to the identifier in order to minimize such issues:

```
Foo *x, y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat `*` for every variable defined:

```
Foo *x = f,
    *y = f;
```

else, you are declaring `x` as `Foo*` and `y` as `Foo` (which can not received a `Foo*` value) as `Foo *x = f, y = f;` is equivalent to `Foo *x = f; Foo y = f;` not `Foo *x = f; Foo *y = f;` as one could think...